# Extract similar numbers from each row to make into new data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

matrix.Names.

```
Per1_23_3_Map1_Ext_5

Per1_24_2_Map2_Ext_5

Per2_23_3_Map1_Ext_5

Per2_25_1_Map2_Ext_5
```

It goes on like this for many rows. Is there any way I can use R code to extract the 23, 24, or 25 in each row and put them into their own data frame? Whether it is 23, 24, or 25 in any particular row is random.

Comment: See `?substr`. Try `substr("Per1_23_3_Map1_Ext_5", 1, 3)` for example to try it out.

Comment: But how do I apply this to more than one row at a time?

Comment: As noted in `?substr` the function is vectorized, so you can replace the string with the name of the variable and it will operate on each element.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
sort(as.numeric(str_extract(v1, "(?<=_)[0-9]+")))
```

---

Or another option is `sub`

```
sort(as.numeric(sub("^[^_]+_(\\d+).*", "\\1", v1)))
```